# Stretch in Infinitesimal strain theory

Tags: fluid-mechanics, mathematics, solid-mechanics

[image: 7]

In the picture above we have the expression of stretch with respect to strain tensor, but in case of infinitesimal strain theory, we take stretch equal to 1+T.E.T

I don't understand why by taking Taylor series expansion, the answer would be 1+ x, with x= T.E.T, with my calculation, the first derivative is 1/radical(1+2x) not x

Comment: Did you ever learn about the Binomial Theorem? This is just expanding the square root as a series, and ignoring the higher order terms (which is what "infinitesimal" means).

Comment: I know its a taylor series expansion, but when I calculated it, the first derivative gave 1/radical(1+2x) , and not x. So this is why I'm not convinced with the answer. I have edited my question

Comment: Because derivative of radical U is U'/2*radical U

Comment: You're expanding the series at $x = 0$.  That means the denominator of the derivative is equal to 1.  See https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/calculus/maclaurin-series-of-sqrt1x.html

Comment: Taylor series is doing it the hard way. The Binomial theorem says $(1 + a)^{1/2}  = 1 + \frac 1 2a + (\frac1 2)(\frac 1 2-1)(\frac 1 {2!})a^2 + \dots$.

Comment: Thank you Biswajit and alephzero :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor is straightforward:
$$
\sqrt{1+2x}
=\left.\sqrt{1+2x}\right|_0 
+\left.{d \over dx}\sqrt{1+2x}\right|_0x 
+O(x^2) \\
=1 
+\left.{d \over dx}{1 \over \sqrt{1+2x}}\right|_0x 
+O(x^2) \\
=1 
+x 
+O(x^2) \\
$$

Note that Taylor holds for matrices variables under some conditions.

ps.If you can handle it, you also have the Generalized [Binomial Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for complex numbers (not matrices)
$$
(x+y)^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\array{r\\k}\right)x^{r-k} y^k \ ,  \ \left(\array{r\\k}\right)={(r)\cdots (r-k+1)\over k!}\\
\sqrt{1+2x}=(1+2x)^{1/2}
=1+\left(\array{1/2\\1}\right)(2x)+O(x^2)\\
=1+{1/2 \over 1!}2x+O(x^2)=1+x+O(x^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The OP's notation isn't very clear, but by any reasonable engineering definition "stretch" is a (real) number, not a matrix. Presumably $T.E.T$ with the underbrace $X$ is a component of some sort of triple product...